# Is it possible to install Python on a server so that any connected computer can use it?

Tags: python, installation

So my office has a company server to which all computers are connected.  I've written a Python script which I would like to make available to all people in the office.  Is there a way to install Python directly on this server such that this is possible?

Now, I know what you're thinking: make it an executable.  I've tried that using `py2exe` and its just been a miserable failure.  The executable it makes is slow, glitchy, and I have to jump through a ton of hoops just to get it to the barely functional state I've managed.  The biggest issue is the use of modules which my program edits.  To get these to update I have  modify a zip archive which does not happen reliably.  Installing Python to the server is the best workaround I can come up with for `py2exe`.  I am asking if it is possible and, if yes, how to do it.   If it's not, I'd love to hear whatever workaround y'all can come up with.

**EDIT:** Things I forgot so say, the server is Windows 64-bit, and I would prefer to not modify it directly (ie, I would like to do everything from my computer if possible)

Things I tried:

- Installing vanilla Python directly onto the server.  This didn't work since the actual dlls were not accesible to other machines on the LAN
- Setting up path variables through the network to a machine which has Python installed. This didn't work because of firewalls on the network and such.

Comment: If this is a windows box, yes. Just use the Python installer which will associate '.py' with the Python interpreter. Make sure all necessary libraries are installed (this can be done centrally) and you should be fine. This could also be done over a shared network drive.

Comment: I tried installing Python, and setting the install path to be on the server, but that didn't work. I'm assuming you mean something different, could you clarify the distinction between what you're suggesting and what I tried?

Comment: install `python` in `virtualenv` on remote machine and access it through `SSH`

Comment: Use [portable python](http://portablepython.com/)

Comment: @WayneWerner could I add libraries and modules to the ones not included?

Comment: Yep. You just setup setuptools with `path\to\python.exe setup.py install` and then you can `pip install`. That's currently how I have Python setup on my machine.

Comment: In response to this question being marked as off-topic, I have updated the question to address the first reason.  As for the second reason, this question is about whether it is possible to install Python on a server, which to me, directly involves both programming and programming tools.  But I could be misinterpreting both those terms, so if I am, please clarify what they mean.  Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your trying to run py2exe, I'll assume windows clients for the following.

If they don't have python on their local system you can make a server share and serve out python from that location.

You can run this line in a .bat file

```
\\server\share\distribution\python.exe \\server\share\scripts\my_script.py
```

Comment: What do you mean by "run this line in a .bat file"?  How would I do this?

Comment: First you would need to install a distribution of python in to a share on the server. I picked anaconda from continuum.io.  Share the folder out and make sure you can get to it from a client.  On your windows client open notepad, copy the code line from above and save this as "my.bat" save to the desktop (for now)  double click it to run.  (or open 'cmd' and run it from there)

Comment: So instead of installing python as I normally would, I would install anaconda somewhere on the shared network drive, then have each office member run the bat file, correct?

Comment: That's the idea.  The idea can be extended to be even fancier for powershell if you need that extra security, and that's a different set of questions.

Comment: How would modules such as ```lxml``` work on this? Would I have to install them separately?

Comment: you put them in the site-packages in the server share just like any module.

Answer (score 0):

If you run a *nix environment then the best way would be to use SSH. If you don't use unix then you can still run an SSH server and clients on Windows, it is just slightly more painful. 
 Virtual machines can also be an option.

Depending on the application, it may work as a web application. In which case look into create a web application with Python (there are many tutorials out there).

Edit: So for an SSH server, it basically gives you command line access to a remote machine. If you are on windows you need to install an SSH server. If you are on *nix then you probably have one installed. On the client if it's Windows, you install an app like Putty which allows you to initiate the connection. On a *nix machine you run something like:

```
ssh username@serveraddress
```

And you will get a connection. Then you just browse and run the programs as you normally would at a command line.

Comment: Do you think you could give me a more detailed description of what would be involved with using an SSH server?

Answer (score 0):

On a UNIX system:

```
ssh user@server-ip-address python path/to/myscript.py
```